# How can you capture new information for existing Cognito Forms entries?

Tags: cognito-forms

I created a pre-registration form for summer camps.  Now I need to confirm these registrations and create a signed contract.

1. Is it possible to import the entries in a new form with data already pre-filled?
2. Is it possible to ask the to only enter the missing information required for final registration?
3. Can I require them to digitally sign the contract?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to accomplish this in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com):

1. You can use our prefill feature to create prefill links to send out to your registrants, where the links include entry information from the first form to prefill the second form.
   https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/65/data-integration/prefilling-a-form
2. You can enhance your original form to include the additional information you which to collect, and ask your registrants to complete their registration by sending them an email, through Cognito Forms, that includes a secure link to their registration form.
   https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/79/entries/sharing-entries

Since the second option is by far more elegant and powerful, I will provide a bit more detail on best practices for doing this:

- Add your additional fields to your existing preregistration form, possible in a new section or page for simplicity.
- If you still plan to use this form for pre-registrations, such as for summer camp next year, add a Show This Field - Internally Yes/No field indicating that the registration is ready to be completed.
- For the new fields, sections or pages you added for final registration, select Show This Field - When and make these new fields only appear when you have internally marked the form as ready for final registration.
- Make sure to add a Signature field as one of these new fields, and make this field required.
- Add payment fields to your form to securely collect payment during submission  via Stripe or PayPal.
- Enable Entry Link Sharing under Form Settings on the Build page, to allow you to send out edit links to existing entries.
- Customize the link sharing email template to provide instructions to your registrants.
- Under Entries, select Share and send out your edit links to your registrants.
- When sharing, select Link Expires - When Submitted to ensure that your registrants cannot continue to edit their registration after submission.

Using this approach, these shared registration entries will have a status of Incomplete, which will visually show you which have been resubmitted and which are still awaiting further information.  By making these additional fields only appear when you have approved the pre-registration (by updating the internal field you added), you will be able to use this form for pre-registration next year as well.